# $_POST returning Array () and echoes nothing if I try to index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to pass an object (I think its an object( its an associative array/dictionary with an indexed array for values)) to a PHP file so that I can insert data into a database. Every time I try to access the contents of the array in PHP it returns Array() or Array depending on what I try. I have tried to user `$.ajax()` as well but results in the same problem.

```
function postData()
{
    data = JSON.stringify(dataObject);
    alert(data);
     $.post("submit_order.php",
    data,
    function(status){
        alert(status)
        window.location.href = "submit_order.php";
    });
}
```

This is what the data structure looks like after using `JSON.stringify()`

```
{
    "order":[
       ["2","chicken panini","3.95",1],
       ["1","cakes","3.55",1]
    ]
}
```

This is what I am trying to access the values and the data structure itself. As you can see I have tried all sorts.

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
echo $order[0][0];
echo $_POST['order'][0][0][1];
print_r($_POST['order'][0]);
print_r($_POST['order'][0][1]);
print_r($_POST['order'][0][0][1]);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  echo $key;
}
```

When I `print_r($_POST);` it gives me

> Array()

```
{"order":[["2","chicken panini","3.95",1],["1","cakes","3.55",1],["3","big_cake","2.55",1]]}
```

is sent with the POST request.

Comment: What do you get when you print $_POST? Have you tried using `json_decode` before trying to access the values?

Comment: It returns Array (). and yes I have tried to decode, however it just tells me its an array and not a string. Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in.

Comment: Show what you get when you print_r $_POST.

Comment: It gives me Array ( )

Comment: Please check your developer tool console under XHR request what data is sent with your request.

Comment: {"order":[["2","chicken panini","3.95",1],["1","cakes","3.55",1],["3","big_cake","2.55",1]]}:

Comment: It is definitely sending the right data.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed it is valid json with jsonlint.
{
 "order": [
  ["2", "chicken panini", "3.95", 1],
  ["1", "cakes", "3.55", 1],
  ["3", "big_cake", "2.‌​55", 1]
 ]
} Now i am checking but the problem at php end wait.

Comment: While this won't fix your issue, the way you're attempting to get the array values is incorrect. The period is the concatenater operator. The proper way to get array values is `$array[0]` or `$array['key']`.

Comment: Ah thanks I was trying anything at that point to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function postData()
{
    data = JSON.stringify(dataObject);
    $.post( "submit_order.php", function( data ) {
      alert("success");
    });
}
```

try this function instead.

Comment: It returns success, but I think the issue is on the PHP Side.

Comment: This worked with a few tweaks. Needed to put data in there. Replaced success with the response so I can see what was happening in there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You transfer you data as a JSON string - so you have to `json_decode` it on the PHP side.

```
<?php
    print_r(json_decode($_POST['order']));
?>
```

Comment: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

Comment: Try it with `print_r(json_decode($_POST['order']));` @MRKHANCOMUTILeader

Comment: That gets rid of the error but returns a blank screen.

Comment: Have you bound a `.done` callback-function to your `$.post()` jQuery function? The data is returned to the AJAX request and can be handled in this callback.

Comment: You have the function (it is the third parameter in your `$.post`) but there only redirect to `submit_order.php`. But on this page the data isn't present at all - see also https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for the parameters of jQuery's `$.post`

Comment: the alert I have with the variable status gives me the whole data structure. Is this what you mean?  I will have a look at the documentation too.

Comment: After the alert you just redirect to the URL where you first sent the AJAX request to. But this page doesn't have the data after the redirect. At all a redirect doesn't make sense in this case - AJAX is used to load data asynchronously - no need to load a new page. That's the idea behind AJAX

Comment: It was so that I could see what was happening on the PHP page. Is there another way I can work with the data that was sent ?

Comment: When you send an AJAX request, your goal is to fetch the data without reloading the page - so you can handle it in the callback function (where now your ´alert´ and your ´document.location.href´ are set). For example you can append the output to a DOM element or even process it with php inside this function.

Comment: How should I check to see if the array can be accessed serverside on the php file without loading it?

Answer (score 0):

In your code for the second argument you must send the parameters between {} as:

```
$.post( "submit_order.php", { data: data }, function(status){
        alert(status)
        window.location.href = "submit_order.php";
    } );
```

Comment: The data is now sent as -   data:{"order":[["2","chicken panini","3.95",1],["1","cakes","3.55",1],["3","big_cake","2.55",1]]}   I still get Array() when I try to print_r it.

Comment: and if you print $_POST["data"]; ?

Comment: Completely empty again.

Comment: I have also modified the data structure so it is not an object but an indexed array so the data that is sent is data:[["2","chicken panini","3.95",1],["1","cakes","3.55",1],["3","big_cake","2.‌​55",1]]

Comment: @MR KHAN COMUTI Leader I reproduced the entire code on my end and i was able to print in php the data. Your print issues are before or after you close the alert ?

Comment: after the alert, on the PHP page that is loaded.

Comment: if is after the alert it will be always empty because there is not a post, but a get.

First time you make a post request using your function and then you make another get request with window.location.href to submit_order.php

Comment: print in your php file and use a die to stop the request there.

Comment: @MRKHANCOMUTILeader if I need to explain better please tell me

Comment: I understand what your saying about the problem but the second part im not sure about.  What should I do to fix it.  How can I check the data that has been sent to the server so I can use it in the php code

Comment: @MRKHANCOMUTILeader when you want to debug in php use die(); to stop the script there, after your print

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['order])){
  $_POST['order] = json_decode($_POST['order]);    
  foreach($_POST['order'] as $order_key => $order_value){
   echo $order_key ." =>". $order_value;
  }
}
?>
```

Try this :)

Comment: It is still blank.

Comment: Does that mean that nothing is in POST?

Comment: yes please try print_r($_POST) if it will be blank then you have problem in posting data not at retriving time.

Comment: It gives me this: Array ( ). Which hopefully means it has an array there.

Comment: no it mean blank array you got some problem while you are posting your data.

Comment: the status variable shows the whole data structure.. I can't seem to find where the problem is?

Comment: i have added postData function for you check and try it.http://stackoverflow.com/a/40241265/2870548

Comment: You have a typo. The syntax highlighting makes it obvious